# My template mixes up internal links between appendix and main text (some for footnotes)

Tags: footnotes, templates, links, appendix, bugs

When I add an appendix with `\appendix` and then put an internal link to anything in it with a `\label{name}`/`ref{name}`, it sends me in the main text. For instance, I want to go to section B.3. Instead, I will be send to section 2.3 ! Same for any labels (I'm working with Overleaf).

Other problem: when I click in an internal link of a footnote, it sends me to page number 1 (e.g. `\footnote{this is a footnote}` will send me to the title page instead of the footnote at the end of the actual page).

Here is an example of `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{ABCreport}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Anything}

I love chapter \ref{aaa}.

\appendix

\chapter{This is a chapter in the appendix}
\label{aaa}

I love this chapter, and it's chapter \ref{aaa}.
\footnote{This is a nice footnote. Try clicking on the "1" in the text}


\end{document}
```

Here is the complete file of the template I'm using:

```
%%%% Template for ABC report %%%%
      

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ABCreport}
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

%%%%Structure%%%%

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Language
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage[french]{babel}
%silence the annoying warning
\frenchsetup{SuppressWarning}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}


\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

%%%%package tikz%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\RequirePackage{chemfig}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%%%%Forme%%%%

%Chapter form
\RequirePackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
%Picture package
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{eurosym}
\RequirePackage{mwe}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{ccaption}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{framed}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{fourier}
\RequirePackage[pages=some]{background}

%%%%Math%%%%

\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\RequirePackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\RequirePackage{esint}

%%%%Annexe%%%%

\RequirePackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\linespread{1.5}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexes}

%%%%Couleurs%%%%

\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}
\definecolor{bleu}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{rouge}{rgb}{0.77, 0.12, 0.23}
\definecolor{vert}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.13}
\definecolor{antiquefuchsia}{rgb}{0.57, 0.36, 0.51}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{cyan!30!white}
\colorlet{framecolor}{blue!50!black}

%%%%Custom command%%%%

\newcommand{\rouge}[1]{\textcolor{rouge}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bleu}[1]{\textcolor{bleu}{#1}}
\newcommand{\verts}[1]{\textcolor{vert}{#1}}

\makeatletter

%Keys for title page
\define@cmdkey [PRE] {fam} {title}{}
\define@cmdkey [PRE] {fam} {studies}{}
\define@cmdkey [PRE] {fam} {course}{}
\define@cmdkey [PRE] {fam} {author}{}
\define@cmdkey [PRE] {fam} {teacher}{}
\define@cmdkey [PRE] {fam} {date}{}
\define@cmdkey [PRE] {fam} {logo}{}
\define@cmdkey [PRE] {fam} {manyAuthor}[1]{}
%Set default value for the keys (used if not specified)
\presetkeys         [PRE] {fam} {title=titre,
                                 studies=,
                                 course=,
                                 author=Auteurs,
                                 teacher=,
                                 date=,
                                 logo=7,
                                 manyAuthor=8,}{}
\tikzset{vertical custom shading/.code={%
 \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@middle{#1}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@bottom{\tikz@vcs@middle/2}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@vcs@top{(100-\tikz@vcs@middle)/2+\tikz@vcs@middle}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom]{newaxis}{100bp}{%
  color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
  color(\tikz@vcs@bottom bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
  color(\tikz@vcs@middle bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
  color(\tikz@vcs@top bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
  color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)}
  \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/shading=newaxis}
  }
}

% Title command
\newcommand*{\titleABC}[1]{\setkeys[PRE]{fam}{#1}

    \begingroup
    \BgThispage
    % Replace logo with nothing if not specified
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\cmdPRE@fam@logo}{7}}{}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=6cm,keepaspectratio]{\cmdPRE@fam@logo}\\}
    {\cmdPRE@fam@studies}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    {\bfseries \cmdPRE@fam@course}\\[\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\Huge \cmdPRE@fam@title}\\[\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\cmdPRE@fam@manyAuthor}{8}}{
    {\Large \cmdPRE@fam@author}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\bfseries \cmdPRE@fam@teacher}}{
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft} \large
            \cmdPRE@fam@author
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright} \large
            \cmdPRE@fam@teacher
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \vfill
    {\cmdPRE@fam@date}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
\endgroup}

% Fix on chapter overful hbox
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}%
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}%     % Amount of space by which the
%                                  % number is shifted right
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbox[gray]{.85}{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
\kern-\myhi
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\color[gray]{.5}\CNoV\thechapter}%
%\kern-\myhi
\\%
  }

\makeatother

%Boxed environement
\newenvironment{frshaded*}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

%Command to put the seal of ABC in Background of the first page
\newcommand{\sceau}[1]{\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.05,
angle=10,
position={12cm,-22cm},
contents={%
  \includegraphics[height=20cm,width=20cm,keepaspectratio]{#1}
  }%
}}

%Add small heading in the left corner of the page.
\pagestyle{headings}

%This is used to force the label alphabetic for the citation of biblio
% begin: excerpt from `alphabetic.bbx'
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
 
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
   {\list
      {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
         \printfield{prefixnumber}%
     \printfield{labelalpha}%
         \printfield{extraalpha}}}
      {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
       \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
       \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
       \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
       \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
       \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
   {\endlist}
   {\item}
% end: excerpt from `alphabetic.bbx'
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is just edited my question with an example of `main.tex` (no other file is required)

Comment: You do get warned `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{chapter.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored` and `pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`

Comment: oh ! Thanks. Where should I change that (as it's not in the template ?) I forgot to say I worked in Overleaf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hyperref`should almost always be loaded late, moving

```
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

to the last line of your class file removes the link warnings and **1** links to the right page.

You should also remove `\makeatletter` (which does nothing in a class file) and `\makeatother` (which does nothing here but would break most class files as it removes access to package level commands with `@`)

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle you are the best !